# ruby/rails: How to determine if module is included?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, module

Expanding on my question here ([ruby/rails: extending or including other modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28575328/ruby-rails-extending-or-including-other-modules)), using my existing solution, what's the best way to determine if my module is included?

What I did for now was I defined instance methods on each module so when they get included a method would be available, and then I just added a catcher (`method_missing()`) to the parent module so I can catch if they are not included. My solution code looks like:

```
module Features
  FEATURES = [Running, Walking]

  # include Features::Running
  FEATURES.each do |feature|
    include feature
  end

  module ClassMethods
    # include Features::Running::ClassMethods
    FEATURES.each do |feature|
      include feature::ClassMethods
    end
  end

  module InstanceMethods
    def method_missing(meth)
      # Catch feature checks that are not included in models to return false
      if meth[-1] == '?' && meth.to_s =~ /can_(\w+)\z?/
        false
      else
        # You *must* call super if you don't handle the method,
        # otherwise you'll mess up Ruby's method lookup
        super
      end
    end
  end

  def self.included(base)
    base.send :extend, ClassMethods
    base.send :include, InstanceMethods
  end
end

# lib/features/running.rb
module Features::Running
  module ClassMethods
    def can_run
      ...

      # Define a method to have model know a way they have that feature
      define_method(:can_run?) { true }
    end
  end
end

# lib/features/walking.rb
module Features::Walking
  module ClassMethods
    def can_walk
      ...

      # Define a method to have model know a way they have that feature
      define_method(:can_walk?) { true }
    end
  end
end
```

So in my models I have:

```
# Sample models
class Man < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include features modules
  include Features

  # Define what man can do
  can_walk
  can_run
end

class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include features modules
  include Features

  # Define what man can do
  can_run
end
```

And then I can

```
Man.new.can_walk?
# => true
Car.new.can_run?
# => true
Car.new.can_walk? # method_missing catches this
# => false
```

Did I write this correctly? Or is there a better way?

Comment: The question is a bit convoluted, so I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for but to check if a model is included you can do `object.class.include? Module`

Comment: You can use `respond_to?` to check if a method is available.

Answer (score 69):

If I understand your question correctly, you can use [`Module#include?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Module.html#method-i-include-3F):

```rb
Man.include?(Features)
```

For example:

```rb
module M
end

class C
  include M
end

C.include?(M) # => true
```

### Other ways

#### Checking [`Module#included_modules`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Module.html#method-i-included_modules)

This works, but it's a bit more indirect, since it generates intermediate `included_modules` array.

```rb
C.included_modules.include?(M) # => true
```

since `C.included_modules` has a value of `[M, Kernel]`

#### Checking [`Module#ancestors`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Module.html#method-i-ancestors)

```rb
C.ancestors.include?(M) #=> true
```

since `C.ancestors` has a value of `[C, M, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]`

#### Using operators like `<`

The `Module` class also declares several comparison operators:

- [`Module#<`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Module.html#method-i-3C)
- [`Module#<=`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Module.html#method-i-3C-3D)
- [`Module#==`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Module.html#method-i-3D-3D)
- [`Module#>=`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Module.html#method-i-3E-3D)
- [`Module#>`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Module.html#method-i-3E)

Example:

```rb
C < M # => true
```

Comment: Upvoted for the `C < M` syntax. Do you know where I can learn about sugar syntax like that? I have yet to find a Ruby equivalent of "Thinking in Java", a thorough introduction to the language.

Comment: @makhan, it's the method [Module#<](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/Module.html#method-i-3C).

Comment: @makhan "Eloquent Ruby" from Russ Olsen is a nice (and qiet comprehensive) overview of Ruby idoms.

Comment: Correct code is:
`Man.included_modules.include?(Features)` instead of `includes?`  I tried to edit the anwer, but you need to change more than 6 chars to edit and the rest of this post seems good :-)

Comment: @CarySwoveland I just edited the answer, quite significantly. I added more formatting, links to the relevant API documentation, and I change the first approach mentioned to be the "idomatic" on `Man.include?(Feature)` instead of `Man.included_modules.include?(Feature)`. If you think I over stepped, feel free to revert it. Let me know what you think!

Comment: Thank you, @Alexander. A definite improvement.