# Guaranteeing that module includer classes include another module in Ruby

Tags: ruby, logging, module, semantic-logger

I am using the SemanticLogger for logging. It provides a `Loggable` module that classes can include to create `logger` class and instance methods that return a class-specific logger object.

I am working with a module in my own code base that requires access to a `logger` method in its instance methods. If I call `include SemanticLogger::Loggable` in the module, it makes a logger method accessible to module "class" methods, but not instance methods, since modules don't have instances and the module instance methods become methods of the including class.

So for the logger call not to fail, I need to ensure that any class that includes my module also includes SemanticLogger::Loggable. What's the best way to deal with this? Maybe this?:

```
module MyModule
# ...
  def included(_includer_module_or_class)
    require 'semantic_logger'
    include SemanticLogger::Loggable
  end
...
end
```

Comment: I believe this is what you need: [ruby/rails: How to determine if module is included?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28667474/ruby-rails-how-to-determine-if-module-is-included)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### SemanticLogger is a Class-Level Mixin

SemanticLogger is a complex bit of code, and some of its internals aren't very well documented. The key to understanding what it's really doing (and why you're having problems) is that under the hood it's really creating class-level objects that are then accessible to instances. In particular, `:logger` is an accessor defined in the context of the including class, which is why you can't simply add it to an #included block without being very explicit about what *self* is when you `include SemanticLogger::Loggable`.

### Call #class_exec on the Including Class

Once you understand that, the solution becomes a little more self-evident: you have to call [Module#class_exec](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Module.html#method-i-class_exec) on the including class *inside* the module method `:included` when including your module. In other words, make sure #included is a module method and that inside the method *self* is the including class rather than the enclosing module. For example:

```rb
require "bundler/setup"
require "semantic_logger"

module MyModule
  def self.included klass
    klass.class_exec do
      include SemanticLogger
      include SemanticLogger::Loggable

      SemanticLogger[klass]
      # any other class-level configuration you want
      # for SementicLogger or your :logger accessor
    end
  end
end
```

### Mixing Your Customized Logging Module Into a Class

Once you have the mixin properly defined, you can mix it into any class easily. For example:

```rb
class Foo
  include MyModule
end

@foo = Foo.new
```

both the Foo class and the *@foo* instance will have access to SemanticLogger capabilities, and you'll be able to call `@foo.logger.info "Test Message"` on your instance from outside your class, or simply use `:logger` as an accessor from within your Foo class.

If there's a more elegant way to do this, I haven't found it yet. This works consistently for me, and should at least get you started down the right path when using customized SemanticLogger mixins within your own classes.

Comment: I have posted a script that proves this works at https://gist.github.com/keithrbennett/4f3afd8b43e9d202c7da5a2d2f75d95f. Feel free to include it in your answer if you like.

Comment: Todd, what is the `SemanticLogger[klass]` for? I recently learned that this call does not cache/memoize the created value, but rather returns a new instance each time it's called (`def self.[](klass); Logger.new(klass); end`). So setting configuration on it would have no effect on loggers returned by subsequent calls. (Memoization is done by the `logger` methods instead; this surprised me because I thought using your notation would be equivalent to calling `logger`, but it is not.)